# Transformar estrutura de dados de lista para JSON em Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, estrutura-de-dados

Em primeiro lugar, gostaria de apresentar os dados que tenho para resolver um problema que me parece clássico à computação.

1 - Tenho uma lista de caminhos que são retornados em uma chamada de API, gostaria de transformar esses caminhos em uma estrutura parecida com um objeto ou JSON, vejamos abaixo um exemplo do retorno que a API me traz:

[
"curso1/semana01/aula01.mp4",
"curso1/semana01/aula02.mp4",
"curso1/semana02/aula01.mp4",
"curso2/modulo01/aula01.pdf",
]

A partir da estrutura acima desejo criar um objeto JSON no seguinte formato:

```js
curso1: {
    semana01: {
       aula01.mp4,
       aula02.mp4,
    }
}
```

Não sei se consegui explicar da melhor forma o que quero, o fato é que preciso renderizar esses caminhos no meu frontend de uma forma mais organizada, como se fossem uma estrutura de pastas e não uma string qualquer. Estou utilizando Nextjs no Frontend.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se todos os caminhos contidos no seu *Array* tiverem sempre 3 partes, um algoritmo para montar o *JSON* seria:

```js
const paths = [ "curso1/semana01/aula01.mp4", "curso1/semana01/aula02.mp4", "curso1/semana02/aula01.mp4", "curso2/modulo01/aula01.pdf"];

const result = {};
for(let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    const parts = paths[i].split('/');
    if (!result[parts[0]]) result[parts[0]] = {};
    if (!result[parts[0]][parts[1]]) result[parts[0]][parts[1]] = [];
    result[parts[0]][parts[1]].push(parts[2]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Que vai gerar o JSON:

```
{
  "curso1": {
    "semana01": ["aula01.mp4", "aula02.mp4"],
    "semana02": ["aula01.mp4"]
  },
  "curso2": {
    "modulo01": ["aula01.pdf"]
  }
}
```

Comment: faltou o stringify ai @benilson

Comment: @MarceloBatista já tem alguns dias que sugeri a edição desta questão, mas não modifiquei o código original, só coloquei para funcionar no snippet do SOpt.